# How to remove installed GNOME user shell themes

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, gnome-tweak-tool

I have installed some GNOME shell themes through **GNOME Tweaks** and **User Shell Theme Extensions**. I also made some shell theme mods and installed as zip files. Now, I want to remove some unused shell themes, but, also if I delete the folders and zip files, the choices under the User Shell options in GNOME Tweaks still remain.

[image]

How can I remove these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Close and reopen it!

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to know the path where the installed user shell themes are stored, so I can delete them.

Comment: @cialu how did you install it?

Comment: I have installed as zip files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two possibilities.

when you installed themes via scripts provided by author or zip files, they would either copied into 
`~/.local/share/themes/` or `/usr/share/themes/`

you need to go to those folders and find the corresponding theme names to delete them.

please be careful, this themes folder contains GTK+ themes also.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need, they were under `~/.local/share/themes/`. Thanks.