# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome, changing window theme from standard to dark doesn't work

Tags: gnome, themes

I tried to install a theme and somehow it went wrong and I was not satisfied with the results so I removed. After that I tried to restore the initial settings and everything got restored, when I try to change the window theme, now it does not do anything anymore. Any idea where I could look to fix this or any solution?

Theme that I installed was [this.](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/08/yaru-colors-ubuntu)

And I removed by following [this.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092769/how-to-remove-installed-gnome-user-shell-themes)

Below I am including a screenshot which describes my problem better.

[image]

Comment: Provide details on how you added your theme and how you removed your theme. That it does not anymore work could be caused by the way you proceeded.

Comment: @vanadium added the theme that I installed and also the commands that i used to uninstall, from a askubuntu answer.